Manga/manhwa where a black-haired princess gets treated badly and makes a plan to get kidnapped; her blond sister is loved
The girl has been reincarnated into a book. She has black hair and is treated badly even though she's a princess. Everyone loves her blonde sister. She knows that her sister's going to get kidnapped, so she creates a plan to get herself kidnapped instead. And it works. The guy who's engaged to the blonde sister, sends men out to find the black haired sister. And it fails. The guy who kidnapped her has a very rare hair color in their world, (white or black, but I think black though) and he brings her to somewhere in the snowy woods. They both fall in love with each other and get married eventually I think. Again it's a manga/manhwa I'd love help finding it

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

This is The Psycho Duke and I. It is licensed by Pocket Comics.

The Duke just kidnapped her — but little does he know, this is all going exactly according to her plan… When Diana initially lets herself get kidnapped by a bloodthirsty duke from an enemy empire, it's to avoid a certain death that will reduce her character's significance to nothing.

The protagonist transmigrates into a book she knows the plot to, as a black-haired side character. Her character is killed off early on after being falsely accused of kidnapping her blonde sister. She decides to escape her abusive family by being kidnapped instead.

Her plan is to attend the dance the kidnapping occurs at by going as her sister's maid. The car they're in is taken over by the male lead. He didn't expect to find both girls, and kicks the blonde sister out.
The male lead has white hair, which is explicitly mentioned to be rare. Black hair appears to also be rare, as a black-haired man at the party states that he's surprised to see another "raven hair".

